# Exporting multiple results to same Excel Sheet

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have this Macro A. Every time I run it, I get a result as the image below (include 2 tables and 1 graph). Note that this time I copied them from SAS output window and paste it on Excel then format it manually. My question is, when I run Macro A multiple times, how can I export all the results to a single specific Excel Sheet, one after another automatically?

Since I'm kinda a beginner in SAS, so a simple solution is preferred :)

Thanks a bunch!!

[SAS result in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IzM0.jpg)

Comment: After 2 runs, do you need 2 lots of output on the same worksheet, or 2 worksheets in the same workbook, or 2 separate workbooks?

Comment: I want 2 lots of output on the same worksheet, each lot contains 2 tables and 1 graph.

Comment: How about if you proc append the results to file in work and have second macro, which will export the results to excel file?

Comment: @pinegulf: is it possible? I thought that appending results would generate a table contain the result of every run but what I want is each result jump in seperated lots in excel. Also, maybe I'm wrong but I don't think you can store graphs in a file in WORK.

Comment: Use ODS Excel or Tagsets and put the open/close before/after your macro call. You may need to modify your macro to start a new sheet. Do you have SAS 9.4? You need it to create graphs directly in the Excel file.

Comment: Yeah I have SAS 9.4, can you point me in the direction of how I would creat graphs in Excel?

Comment: Use SGPLOT. The graphs will get created in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ODS Excel and sheet_interval option. This assumes SAS 9.4+

```
 Ods excel file='myfile.xlsx' options(sheet_interval='none') style=meadow;

 %macro_run();

 Ods excel close;
```

Within the macro you may need to add:

```
Ods excel options(sheet_interval='none');
```

Comment: Is there anyway that I can choose specific cells in a worksheet to write datas on with ODS Excel? Since I want multiple results go in a same worksheet, I don't want them to be overlapped.

Comment: No, you can't choose the specific cells but SAS defaults shouldn't create  overlap results. If it does, post an example to replicate the issue.

Comment: It works well, the results don't overlap but the format needs to be modified a bit. Sweet thanks!